# Jupyter Lab / Notebook No Kernals Avaliable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

When running jupyterlab this error is given

```
[W 2023-07-10 12:42:10.705 ServerApp] Error loading kernelspec 'python3'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 309, in get_all_specs
        spec = self._get_kernel_spec_by_name(kname, resource_dir)
      File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 252, in _get_kernel_spec_by_name
        if not KPF.instance(parent=self.parent).is_provisioner_available(kspec):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 540, in instance
        inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/provisioning/factory.py", line 54, in __init__
        for ep in KernelProvisionerFactory._get_all_provisioners():
      File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/provisioning/factory.py", line 169, in _get_all_provisioners
        return entry_points(group=KernelProvisionerFactory.GROUP_NAME)
    TypeError: entry_points() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'
[W 2023-07-10 12:42:10.716 ServerApp] Error loading kernelspec 'sagemath'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 309, in get_all_specs
        spec = self._get_kernel_spec_by_name(kname, resource_dir)
      File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 252, in _get_kernel_spec_by_name
        if not KPF.instance(parent=self.parent).is_provisioner_available(kspec):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 540, in instance
        inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/provisioning/factory.py", line 54, in __init__
        for ep in KernelProvisionerFactory._get_all_provisioners():
      File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/provisioning/factory.py", line 169, in _get_all_provisioners
        return entry_points(group=KernelProvisionerFactory.GROUP_NAME)
    TypeError: entry_points() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'
```

when running `jupyter kernelspec list` the same error is given

```
[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Error loading kernelspec 'python3'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 309, in get_all_specs
    spec = self._get_kernel_spec_by_name(kname, resource_dir)
  File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 252, in _get_kernel_spec_by_name
    if not KPF.instance(parent=self.parent).is_provisioner_available(kspec):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 540, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/provisioning/factory.py", line 54, in __init__
    for ep in KernelProvisionerFactory._get_all_provisioners():
  File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/provisioning/factory.py", line 169, in _get_all_provisioners
    return entry_points(group=KernelProvisionerFactory.GROUP_NAME)
TypeError: entry_points() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'
[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Error loading kernelspec 'sagemath'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 309, in get_all_specs
    spec = self._get_kernel_spec_by_name(kname, resource_dir)
  File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 252, in _get_kernel_spec_by_name
    if not KPF.instance(parent=self.parent).is_provisioner_available(kspec):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 540, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/provisioning/factory.py", line 54, in __init__
    for ep in KernelProvisionerFactory._get_all_provisioners():
  File "/home/hawve005/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/provisioning/factory.py", line 169, in _get_all_provisioners
    return entry_points(group=KernelProvisionerFactory.GROUP_NAME)
TypeError: entry_points() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'
No kernels available
```

I have reinstalled it already, no dice.
I have python on the computer so it should run fine.
The computer is a lab machine at my university,
so I have no sudo or admin access.
(I'm using thier servers with A100 gpus and personally I think they have done this to me on purpose bc it just stopped working out of the blue, before this they were timming me out)

Comment: Did you see [here](https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/796#issuecomment-890322401) and the notes below it about what seemed to help by fixing `importlib-metadata`? Similar thing [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/4502#issuecomment-1082472145).